# Using $match in aggregation query

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have these values in my Mongodb:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4feb9d573752c8a33a000001"),
"name" : "TSP1",
"Server" : "S1",
"active" : true,
"tag" : "<A HREF=\"[FAST_1]http://www.google.com"><IMG SRC=\"http://ad.google.com.CO/B5981883.7;sz=300x50;ord=[TIMESTAMP]?\" BORDER=0 WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=50 ALT=\"ment\"></A>"
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4feb9d573752c8a33a000001"),
"name" : "TSP2",
"Server" : "S1",
"active" : true,
"tag" : "<A HREF=\"[FAST_1]http://www.google.com"><IMG SRC=\"http://ad.ITG.com.CO/B5981883.7;sz=300x50;ord=[TIMESTAMP]?\" BORDER=0 WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=50 ALT=\"ment\"></A>"
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4feb9d573752c8a33a000003"),
"name" : "TSP3",
"Server" : "S2",
"active" : true,
"tag" : "<A HREF=\"[FAST_2]http://www.google.com"><IMG SRC=\"http://ad.Yahoo.com.CO/B5981883.7;sz=300x50;ord=[TIMESTAMP]?\" BORDER=0 WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=50 ALT=\"ment\"></A>"
}
```

I am trying to get this result out:

```
    "result" : [
    {
        "_id" : "S1",
        "count" : 2
    }]
```

This is the query that i am using:

```
db.creative.aggregate([ { $match : { tag : { $regex : /[FAST_1]/ } }}, { $group: { _id : "$Server", count: { $sum: 1} }} ]);
```

Also, tried this:

```
db.creative.aggregate([ {$match : {"tag" : /[FAST_1]/ }}, { $group: { _id : "$Server", count: { $sum: 1}}} ])
```

But i keep getting this result:

```
    {
        "_id" : "S1",
        "count" : 2
    },
    {
        "_id" : "S2",
        "count" : 1
    }
```

Even if i change FAST_1 to FAST_2 i get the same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the regex around the braces [ ].

```
db.creative.aggregate([ { $match : { tag : { $regex : /\[FAST_1\]/ } }},  ...
```